# How to insert data in the table without substituting the variable?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake-task

I have a rake file that create a lot of items.

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :seed do
    desc "items table"
      task :items=> :environment do
        Item.create(name: "first_name", process: "clean the item #{test} then pack and send to #{location}")
        ................................................
      end
  end
end
```

when i do `rake db:seed:items` I am not able to insert this data in the table without substituting the variable. Is there a way to insert this data without variable substitution so that i can substitute the variable later?

Comment: Do you mean you want to defer interpolation of `#{test}` until later? Sometimes it's easier to use a simple template system like [Handlebars](https://github.com/cowboyd/handlebars.rb) to represent that.

Comment: @tadman What I did is i used single quote to insert the data in the table. but i am struggling to do variable substitution later ?

Comment: Ah, now we have a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to defer interpolation to a later time and still use the Ruby string interpolation notation, you can do this:

```
string = 'clean the item #{test} then pack and send to #{location}'
values = {
  test: "paperclip",
  location: "head office"
}

string.gsub(/\#\{([^}]+)\}/) do
  values[$1.to_sym]
end

# => "clean the item paperclip then pack and send to head office"
```

You can even wrap this up into a simple method:

```
def interpolate(string, values)
  string.gsub(/\#\{([^}]+)\}/) do
    values[$1.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Which, if you wanted to be a bit bold, you could patch into String:

```
class String
  def interpolate(values)
    self.gsub(/\#\{([^}]+)\}/) do
      values[$1.to_sym]
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this only does the most basic interpolation of things like `#{x}` and not `#{x.method_call}` or `#{x+1}` or even `#{x[y]}`. For that you may need to go with a more arbitrary code evaluation method, but that road is paved with danger.